# executing system_profiler via swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Wanting to get a details of all installed applications by executing         `system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType`

The snippet given below works just fine in playground, however gives me `code signing internal problem: unexpected error from xpc` when I try executing it from an application.

```
func shell(_ command: String) -> String {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
    task.arguments = ["-c", command]

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String

    return output
}
print(shell("system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType"))
```

P.S Apologies if this is a dumb question, I'm fairly new to swift and xcode technologies :)

Comment: If the app is sandboxed you can't run shell scripts via `Process`. And please don't use `NSString` in Swift. The line to create a string from `Data` can be *dramatically* reduced to `let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!`

Comment: Oh yeah, I just had to turn off sandboxing. Oh I keep that in mind, thank you!